# C# How to know which element is root object for deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, text, deserialization, information-retrieval

I used json2csharp to get this:

http://pastebin.com/pbDYCrWk

From that, I wish to get the title that is held in the Oembed section.

I'm using this code:

```
        string url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json";
        string jsonText = await DoStuff(url);

        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonText);
        var deserializeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Page.Oembed>(json);

        string test = deserializeObject.title;
```

And I assumed it would work, however on the line with the deserializeObject variable, I get an error saying it can't do it. 
I tried using Page.RootObject however it doesn't work either, and I assumed it would since it seems to be the root.
What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Json2CSharp then it is RootObject:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Should be:

```
var deserializeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JuicyReddit.RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: How come it is not working? It says there was an error converting the value.

Comment: Works for me. I re-created the objects with Json2CSharp and tested with Json.NET & ServiceStack running on iOS and both seem to work. I don't see Page object in the DTO's so are you referencing something else? It should be: 'var deserializeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JuicyReddit.RootObject>(json);'

Comment: Weird :S
The Page object is a class I created to store all of the stuff from the json2sharp website. Juicy Reddit is the project namespace. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the string you get back from the service in correct format?

Comment: the var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonText) returns this:

http://pastebin.com/mcYPm5Tb

Does it look like it should work?

Comment: I think I see the problem, I can't believe I missed it. If the DoStuff returns you the web response as string then just call the DeserializeObject method. SerializeObject is not needed.

Comment: I was thinking that myself.
I have this code now:

            string jsonText = await DoStuff(url);
            Page deserializeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Page>(jsonText);

However, I cannot browse the elements inside of the deserializeObject Page variabble. Any ideas on why this is?